# display an img src inside html then php

Tags: php, html

I would like to ask how to display an img src like this:

```
<html>

<?php

$extradata = (Data for this come from database that I decode)

$profilepicturefinalpath = "/folder/folder/".$extradata;

echo '<img src="<?php echo $profilepicturefinalpath ?>"/>';

?>

</html>
```

What should I do, Is this possible?

Please help, I am just a newbie

Comment: `echo '<img src="', $profilepicturefinalpath, '"/>';`

Comment: You can't echo inside an echo (it's logical if you think about that for a moment). Nor can you start a php code block inside another php code block (again, think about it). Instead just concatenate the variable e.g. `echo '<img src="'.$profilepicturefinalpath.'"/>';`

Comment: It`s working now and I understand. Thank you for your answer. I will do my best to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. Normal echo with double quotes or heredoc

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$extradata = (Data for this come from database that I decode)
$profilepicturefinalpath = "/folder/folder/".$extradata;

echo <<<EOQ
<img src="{$profilepicturefinalpath}" />
EOQ;
echo '<BR>';
echo "<img src='{$profilepicturefinalpath}' />"
echo '<BR>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```